# Tab completion not working for some functions of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

The problem is when i hit the **TAB** after the `tf.nn.` some options are shown. But for example `tf.nn.layers` does not appear. Or when i want to complete `tf.cont` to get `tf.contrib` the only thing appears is `tf.control_dependencies`.

How do i get all the options in auto-completion?

I am using windows 10, python 3.7, pip 10.0.1, jedi = 0.17.2, tensorflow = 2.41, notebook 6.2.0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Tf.contrib` is removed in Tensorflow 2.x versions. It is expected behaviour.

To use `tf.contrib` API's downgrade your Tensorflow version to `TF ==1.15`